# transform a sector image to rectangle image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image: the image with the sector part as the roi]

I am currently working the image to transform the sector part in the image to a rectangle shape.

I tried some ways but don't work well.

Any ideas on how to transform?

Comment: This question is quite broad. I cannot give you an answer that completey solves the problem. I think you might want to look into build in MatLab functions. You will find several tools to strech rotate and reshape images.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a destination image the height of which is the difference in the radii, and the width is the length of the perimeter at middle radius (this ensures square pixels along the middle arc).

Scan this image and for every pixel convert the coordinates (angle, radius) from Cartesian to polar, with a shift to the ROI center. This will give you the corresponding pixel in the source image, which you copy to the destination. Make sure to scale the angle and radius to match the destination image limits to the ROI edges.

As the source coordinates won't be integer, truncating and merely copying the source pixel achieves so-called nearest-neighbor resampling, which features visible artifacts. You can smoothen them by considering four neighboring pixels and interpolating bilinearly between them by means of the fractional parts of the coordinates.

You can even go for bicubic interpolation, using sixteen neighbors. But from my experience, the gain in quality is not so visible.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to assign the pixel values to the destination image. But I didn't make it. is it possible that you can show me the sample code?

Comment: @reachzhu: no, I have not programmed this.